Entity Framework: Save Private Field
I'm using Entity Framework with MongoDB. I have a class, Account with the following field:
private readonly byte[] salt;

Account is configured in Entity Framework like so:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToCollection("accounts");
}

When I save an Account to my database, the corresponding document does not have salt.
How do I store a field or property in my database using Entity Framework whilst keeping it private?

Turns out I just needed to manually add the field for the model.
var account = modelBuilder.Entity<Account>();
account.Property("fieldName");
account.ToCollection("accounts");


You should implement a Backing Field.

Configure Salt property with backing field: salt.

internal class Account : SignInCredentials
{
    private readonly byte[] salt;

    public byte[] Salt
    {
        get { return salt; }
    }

    ...
}


Configure the Salt with the backing field in Fluent API.

internal class MongoDataContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .Property(x => x.Salt)
            .HasField("salt");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .ToCollection("accounts");
    }
}


Demo



Is there a way to do this without making a public property? I don't want salt to be accessible outside Account.
